# Sorting strings in ascending order by a certain value. What is wrong in my implementation?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector, struct

I have the following problem :

**Given a number N and N names, sort the names using a certain value (in ascending order). The names with the same value get sorted alphabetically.**

The value of each name is determined by the number of pairs of vowels or consonants. Thus, each pair of vowels adds 1 to the value of the word, each pair of consonants subtracts 1 from the value, and a vowel-consonant or consonant-vowel pair doesn't change the value of the word.

**What I did :**
I created a vector using a struct. Each element has the name and its value. I calculated the value of each name and gave it to the .value field. After that, I sorted my vector using 2 for loops (I had no efficient idea for a value sort and an alphabetical sort all in one), and displayed the vector.

**What happens:**
I get no result, and I also think that there might be a segmentation fault. I'm still a newbie when it comes to finding out such errors.

Can you give me a few pointers ?

Thank you.

Attached the code below.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
const char voc[] = "aeiouAEIOU";

struct stud
{
    string name;
    int value;
};

typedef vector<stud> vect;

void data(int& n, vect& v)
{
    cin>>n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin>>v[i].name;
    }
}

int getValue(string name)
{
    int value = 0;
    int len = name.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if(strchr(voc, name[i]) && strchr(voc, name[i+1]))
            value++;
        else if(!strchr(voc, name[i]) && !strchr(voc, name[i+1]))
            value--;
    }
    return value;
}

void updateValues(vect& v)
{
    vector<stud>::size_type v_size = v.size();
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < v_size; ++i)
    {
        int value = getValue(v[i].name);
        v[i].value = value;
    }
}

void sortByValue(vect& v)
{
    vector<stud>::size_type v_size = v.size();
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < v_size; ++i)
        for(unsigned j = i+1; j < v_size; ++j)
        {
            if(v[i].value > v[j].value)
                swap(v[i], v[j]);
            else if(v[i].value == v[j].value)
                if(v[i].name.compare(v[j].name) > 0)
                    swap(v[i], v[j]);
        }
}

void display(vect v)
{
    vector<stud>::size_type sz = v.size();
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        cout<<v[i].name<<'\n';
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    vect myvec;

    data(n, myvec);
    updateValues(myvec);
    sortByValue(myvec);

    display(myvec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first thing my IDE complains about is the lack of #include <iostream>

Comment: Second thing is, if you're going to submit challenge questions that take in test values, you should provide test values.

Comment: @Tzalumen Oh, sorry about that, I might have forgotten to paste it here. i have it in my code.

Comment: I recommend Cyrillic McGee's answer, that just about covers anything you want to sort.

Answer (score 1):

better use overload operator> [watch here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)
or use std::sort

```
std::vector<stud> vec;

//read

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) -> bool
{ 
    if (a.value == b.value)
        return a.name > b.name;
    else
        return a.value > b.value

});
```